# hist() within piping and group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, histogram

I'm looking for a way to utilize `dplyr` 's `group_by` functionality to make counts, and a plot-less histogram for `mpg` after grouping_by `gear` and `vs`.

My code is:

```
mtcars %>% 
group_by(gear,vs) %>% 
summarise(counts = count (n), hist(mpg, plot = FALSE, breaks = c(seq(10,40,1))))
```

The error is:

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
>   Column hist(mpg, plot = FALSE, breaks = c(seq(10, 40, 1)))` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 6

I'm not constrained to `dplyr` but that's all I'm familiar with in R at this point.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit perhaps to remove plot-less as to me it's the antipode of a histogram!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what a plotless histogram is, but does this help?

```
mtcars %>%
    mutate(mpgClasses = cut(mpg, 10:40)) %>%
    group_by(gear, vs, mpgClasses) %>%
    summarise(n())
```

You can also rearrange that a little like this

```
mtcars %>%
    mutate(mpgClasses = cut(mpg, 10:40)) %>%
    group_by(gear, vs, mpgClasses) %>%
    summarise(counts = n()) %>%
    spread(mpgClasses, counts)
```

If you can describe a little more, what you are heading for we can find a better solution.

Comment: The base graphics function `hist` returns a count of factors. See `hist`

Answer (score 1):

Here, I'm just extracting the `counts` from the `hist`. Since I have to make it one element for each group, I made it a list.

```
library(dplyr)
x <- mtcars %>% group_by(gear,vs) %>%     
   summarise(counts = n(),
             hcounts =  list(hist(mpg, plot = FALSE, breaks = c(seq(10,40,1)))$counts))

x
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
# # Groups:   gear [?]
# gear    vs counts    hcounts
# <dbl> <dbl>  <int>     <list>
#   1     3     0     12 <int [30]>
#   2     3     1      3 <int [30]>
#   3     4     0      2 <int [30]>
#   4     4     1     10 <int [30]>
#   5     5     0      4 <int [30]>
#   6     5     1      1 <int [30]>

x$hcounts
# [[1]]
# [1] 2 0 0 1 2 3 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```